# continued radical of complex values

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate quantities like $y = \sqrt{-1 + \sqrt{-1 + \sqrt{-1 +\ldots}}}$

The strategy is for complex numbers $x =re^{i\theta}$ in $\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x+ \sqrt{x+\ldots}}}$

where $r\ne 0$ and real and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$

I want to try some values of $x$ that are negative or near $x=0$.

Can you solve the equation and say

$y = 1/2 + 1/2\sqrt{1 + 4re^{i\theta}}$

If it works for $\theta = 0$ does it work for $\theta = \pi$,

If $\theta$ is $\pi$ we have purely imaginary numbers $x$ but there are real solutions for $y$ if $1-4r \geq 0$ or $r\leq 1/4$

I know that $x=0$ is a special point where the continued radical is zero. The function is not right continuous there.

Comment: If $L=\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x+ \sqrt{x+\ldots}}}$ then $L^2-L-x = 0$ and you can solve it using the quadradic formula.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @CyclotomicField, but would like to *extend* his comment.  The roots of the corresponding quadratic will represent **candidate** values, where **at most**, only one of the roots can be correct.  Further, after identifying/eliminating the *incorrect* root, you are then guaranteed that the remaining root is correct if and only if the corresponding sequence is convergent.  So, you then have to prove convergence, before you can assert the value of $~L.$

Comment: Re previous comment, this means that you have to prove the convergence of the sequence $~\langle a_n\rangle,~$ where $~\displaystyle a_1 = \sqrt{-1}, ~a_2 = \sqrt{-1 + \sqrt{-1}}, ~a_3 = \sqrt{-1 + \sqrt{-1 + \sqrt{-1}}}, \cdots .$  Then, the analysis in the comment of @CyclotomicField will hold, precisely because (it can be shown that) the function $~f(x) = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{\cdots}}}~$ is continuous at $~x = -1.$

Comment: By the way: the posted problem $~\displaystyle \sqrt{-1 + \sqrt{-1 + \sqrt{-1 + \sqrt{...}}}}~$ is not well defined, since in Complex Analysis, $~\sqrt{-1}~$ is itself ambigous.  It can refer to either $~e^{i\pi/2}~$ or $~e^{-i\pi/2}.$